# Run Time Error 13 :-(

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've created a Search Form. My Search Form contain a subform and I've been trying to get the Search button to work. My Search button will help me to run the Search form based by Date and Product.

I've keep getting the error on "Run Time error 13"

The error is at the line which have ***

Would really appreciate if someone assist me on this Search Form. Thanks! :-)

These are my codes

```
Private Sub Search_Click()

    Dim strProduct As String
    Dim strDatePicker As Date
    Dim sql As String

    sql = "select * from 2_WIP where "
    strDatePicker = format(Me.DatePicker, "dd/mm/yyyy")

    If IsDate(Me.DatePicker) Then
       ***strDatePicker = " [Date] Like '*'"***
    Else
       strDatePicker = " [Date] = '" & Me.DatePicker & "'"
    End If

    If IsNull(Me.Product) Then
       strProduct = " [Product] like '*'"
    Else
       strProduct = " [Product] like '" & Me.Product & "'"
    End If

    sql = strDatePicker & "and" & strProduct

    Me.subfrmWIP.Form.RecordSource = sql
    Me.subfrmWIP.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

Comment: strDatePicker is a Date.  you're assigning it a string value.

Comment: `Dim strDatePicker As Date` - this is textbook exactly why I hate Hungarian Notation.

Comment: @jdigital and how do I make it to stay as a date? sorry im not a pro in codings especially on dates

Comment: even Hungarians don't know if `strDatePicker` is a `String`, a `Date`, a `DatePicker` or a `StringDatePicker`

Comment: @ThunderFrame your point

Comment: @Natasha it shouldn't be a `Date`.  it should be a `String`.

Comment: @jdigital not sure if it works but now i receive a run time error 2580 stating "The record source '[Date] = '22/11/2016' and [Product] like '*'" specified on this form or report does not exist." :-(

Comment: There's another problem further down in your code.  Should be 
`sql = sql + strDatePicker & " and " & strProduct`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve your question. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) including the link "How to ask questions the smart way."

Comment: Please don't invalidate given answers with edits. If your question was answered please mark it as accepted. SO is a Q&A site, and people will look for answers here when they run into similar issues.

Comment: sure thing thanks for the notice @Mat'sMug

Comment: i received a run time error 3071 now :-( @jdigital

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the error because you are trying to assign a non-date string value to a date variable.

```
Dim strDatePicker As Date
strDatePicker = " [Date] Like '*'"
```

This assignment is backwards.

```
If IsDate(Me.DatePicker) Then
   ***strDatePicker = " [Date] Like '*'"***
Else
   strDatePicker = " [Date] = '" & Me.DatePicker & "'"
End If
```

---

```
Private Sub Search_Click()

    Dim ProductSearch As String, DateSearch As String
    Dim sql As String

    sql = "SELECT * FROM 2_WIP WHERE "

    If IsDate(Me.DatePicker) Then
        DateSearch = "(([2_WIP].[Date])>=#" & DateValue(Me.DatePicker) & _
        "# And ([2_WIP].[Date])<#" & DateValue(Me.DatePicker) + 1 & "#) "
    Else
        DateSearch = " [Date] Like '*'"
    End If

    If IsNull(Me.Product) Then
        ProductSearch = " [Product] like '*'"
    Else
        ProductSearch = " [Product] like '" & Me.Product & "'"
    End If

    sql = sql & DateSearch & " AND " & ProductSearch

    Me.subfrmWIP.Form.RecordSource = sql
    Me.subfrmWIP.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

### Sample Output

> SELECT * FROM 2_WIP WHERE  [Date] = #11/23/2016# AND  [Product] like '16oz Coke'

### How use Query Builder to help build SQL in the VBA

[image]

Comment: Gah, took too long to post, [deleted my draft](http://pastebin.com/jZHkfGHQ). Have an upvote!

Comment: I tried following your codes exactly but there's a compile error stating "Duplicate declaration in current scope" for DateSearch

Comment: I still get the same original error which is run time error 13. and it specifically shows at the line of the `DateSearch = " [Date] = '" & DateValue(Me.DatePicker) & "'"`ProductSearch is strProduct right?

Comment: sorry! i still get the run time error 13 :-( @ThomasInzina

Comment: I made a test stub to refactor my code.  You had misspelled `Product'.  In my updated answer I replaced the single quotes with hashes for the dates.  Sequel Server using single quotes, Access uses hashes for dates.

Comment: it managed to search. however, it only shows one record. i have a few records for the date that i searched

Comment: Copy the sql string, create an empty query, change the query to SQL view, paste the code and then go back to design mode.  Try and tweak it from there.  When you get the desired result update your code.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I got me a RubberDuck, it Rocks!!  It's awesome having Extract method and Code Inspection in the VBE.  I found out that Office 365 installs the 32 bit version by default.  I'm not going to upgrade till you fully integrate Smart Indenter.  I also loaded your source code into Visual Studios.  I'm going to check it out in a week or so.

Comment: @ThomasInzina awesome!! The current 2.0.10 build has Smart Indenter up and running smoothly btw =)

Comment: @Mat'sMug Sweet! I'll have to check it out.  Once it becomes the current release, I'll definitely start promoting it.  I'm very interested in learning how it all works.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Awesome!  Thanks again!

Comment: im sorry im confused but i tried. i still get to display only one record @ThomasInzina

Comment: When you get less records than you expect when using  a date, alway check to see if the date field has time values.  I updated my answer to handle that situation and added a demo "How use Query Builder to help build SQL in the VBA".

Comment: THANK YOU! :-) @ThomasInzina